# Could not find method implementation() for arguments [org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.50]

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, gradle

I am new to Android development and Flutter too. While Exporting my app I am getting lots of errors where currently stuck on this error. Don't know how to solve this. It would be of great help if you people can help me!

Getting this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'F:\GAMES\quiz\android\app\build.gradle' line: 88

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.50] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDepen
dencyHandler.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                       4.3s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

I think there must be some error in gradle file thus including gradle file below:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("key.properties")
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
    kapt { generateStubs = true }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.karat18.quiz"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            profile {
                matchingFallbacks = ['debug', 'release']
            }
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
        //testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        //androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
        //androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
        //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.1'

    }
    allprojects {
        // ...

        repositories {
            // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
            google()  // Google's Maven repository
            // ...
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dependencies` block in which you added `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"` is inside the `buildscript` block.
This means you are trying to modify the dependencies used by the build and not the ones used by the project.

- Build dependencies only use the `classpath` configuration, so if that is your goal, replace `implementation` by `classpath`.
- Project dependencies have to be declared in a `dependencies` block that is at the same level as the `android` block. See the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies) for details. So if that is your goal, move the line to a new `dependencies` block

Answer (score 0):

In build.gradle (Module:app) replace

> implementation
>   "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

with

> implementation
>   "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"

and in build.gradle (Module:project) change version to

> ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.0'

Comment: Don't know what worked but after copying and running the codes into a new project file, it shows no such error anymore!